# sshexec ant task: environment variables

Tags: ant, build, ssh

I'm using SSHExec ant task to connect to a remote host and I depend on the environment variables that are set on the remote host in order to be able to successfully execute some commands.

```
<sshexec host="somehost"
    username="${username}"
    password="${password}"
    command="set"/>
```

Using the task the env. variables that are outputed are not the same as the ones I get when I log in using an SSH Client.

How can I make the env. variables of the remote host avaiable for the session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is something you can do about the fact it doesn't start a shell.  Use the following:

```
<sshexec command="/bin/bash -l yourScript.sh" .../>
```

Using /bin/bash -l will start an login shell then execute your script within that shell.  It would be exactly as if you had a version of sshexec that properly starts up a login shell. It has to be a script.  If you want to run a single executable command you can do this:

```
<sshexec command="/bin/bash -l -c 'echo $CATALINA_HOME'" .../>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found out that the current SSHExeec task implementation is using JSCh's ChannelExec (remote execution of commands) instead of a ChannelShell (remote shell) as connection channel.

That means that apparentely as per JSCh's current implementation a ChannelExec doesn't load env. variables.

I'm still not sure wether this is a limitation on the protocol or on the API.

**The conclusion is that as for now there's no solution for the problem, unless you implement your own Ant task.**

A working draft of how it would be:

```
package org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PipedInputStream;
import java.io.PipedOutputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;

import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
import org.apache.tools.ant.Project;
import org.apache.tools.ant.types.Resource;
import org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.FileResource;
import org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils;
import org.apache.tools.ant.util.KeepAliveOutputStream;
import org.apache.tools.ant.util.TeeOutputStream;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

/**
 * Executes a command on a remote machine via ssh.
 * @since     Ant 1.6 (created February 2, 2003)
 */
public class SSHExecShellSupport extends SSHBase {

    private static final String COMMAND_SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
    private static final int RETRY_INTERVAL = 500;

    /** the command to execute via ssh */
    private String command = null;

    /** units are milliseconds, default is 0=infinite */
    private long maxwait = 0;

    /** for waiting for the command to finish */
    private Thread thread = null;

    private String outputProperty = null;   // like <exec>
    private File outputFile = null;   // like <exec>
    private boolean append = false;   // like <exec>

    private Resource commandResource = null;
    private boolean isShellMode;
    private long maxTimeWithoutAnyData = 1000*10;

    private static final String TIMEOUT_MESSAGE =
        "Timeout period exceeded, connection dropped.";

    public long getMaxTimeWithoutAnyData() {
        return maxTimeWithoutAnyData;
    }

    public void setMaxTimeWithoutAnyData(long maxTimeWithoutAnyData) {
        this.maxTimeWithoutAnyData = maxTimeWithoutAnyData;
    }

    public boolean isShellMode() {
        return isShellMode;
    }

    public void setShellMode(boolean isShellMode) {
        this.isShellMode = isShellMode;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for SSHExecTask.
     */
    public SSHExecShellSupport() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the command to execute on the remote host.
     *
     * @param command  The new command value
     */
    public void setCommand(String command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a commandResource from a file
     * @param f the value to use.
     * @since Ant 1.7.1
     */
    public void setCommandResource(String f) {
        this.commandResource = new FileResource(new File(f));
    }

    /**
     * The connection can be dropped after a specified number of
     * milliseconds. This is sometimes useful when a connection may be
     * flaky. Default is 0, which means &quot;wait forever&quot;.
     *
     * @param timeout  The new timeout value in seconds
     */
    public void setTimeout(long timeout) {
        maxwait = timeout;
    }

    /**
     * If used, stores the output of the command to the given file.
     *
     * @param output  The file to write to.
     */
    public void setOutput(File output) {
        outputFile = output;
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the output is appended to the file given in
     * <code>setOutput</code>. Default is false, that is, overwrite
     * the file.
     *
     * @param append  True to append to an existing file, false to overwrite.
     */
    public void setAppend(boolean append) {
        this.append = append;
    }

    /**
     * If set, the output of the command will be stored in the given property.
     *
     * @param property  The name of the property in which the command output
     *      will be stored.
     */
    public void setOutputproperty(String property) {
        outputProperty = property;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the command on the remote host.
     *
     * @exception BuildException  Most likely a network error or bad parameter.
     */
    public void execute() throws BuildException {
        if (getHost() == null) {
            throw new BuildException("Host is required.");
        }
        if (getUserInfo().getName() == null) {
            throw new BuildException("Username is required.");
        }
        if (getUserInfo().getKeyfile() == null
            && getUserInfo().getPassword() == null) {
            throw new BuildException("Password or Keyfile is required.");
        }
        if (command == null && commandResource == null) {
            throw new BuildException("Command or commandResource is required.");
        }

        if(isShellMode){
            shellMode();
        } else {
            commandMode();
        }

    }

    private void shellMode() {
        final Object lock = new Object();
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = openSession();
            final Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");

            final PipedOutputStream pipedOS = new PipedOutputStream();
            PipedInputStream pipedIS = new PipedInputStream(pipedOS);

            final Thread commandProducerThread = new Thread("CommandsProducerThread"){
                public void run() {
                    BufferedReader br = null;
                    try {
                        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(commandResource.getInputStream()));                       
                        String singleCmd;

                        synchronized (lock) {
                            lock.wait(); // waits for the reception of the very first data (before commands are issued)
                            while ((singleCmd = br.readLine()) != null) {
                                singleCmd += COMMAND_SEPARATOR;
                                log("cmd : " + singleCmd, Project.MSG_INFO);
                                pipedOS.write(singleCmd.getBytes());
                                lock.notify();
                                try {
                                    lock.wait();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    log(e, Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            log("Finished producing commands", Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        log(e, Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        log(e, Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
                    } finally {
                        FileUtils.close(br);
                    }
                }
            };

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final TeeOutputStream tee = new TeeOutputStream(out, new KeepAliveOutputStream(System.out));
            channel.setOutputStream(tee);
            channel.setExtOutputStream(tee);
            channel.setInputStream(pipedIS);
            channel.connect();

            // waits for it to finish receiving data response and then ask for another the producer to issue one more command
            thread = new Thread("DataReceiverThread") {
                public void run() {
                    long lastTimeConsumedData = System.currentTimeMillis(); // initializes the watch
                    try {
                        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
                        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];

                        while (true) {

                            if(thread == null){ // works with maxTimeout (for the whole task to complete)
                                break;
                            }

                            while (in.available() > 0) {
                                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                                lastTimeConsumedData = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                if (i < 0){
                                    break;
                                }
                                tee.write(tmp, 0, i);
                            }

                            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                                log("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus(), Project.MSG_INFO);
                                log("channel.isEOF(): " + channel.isEOF(), Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
                                log("channel.isConnected(): " + channel.isConnected(), Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
                                throw new BuildException("Connection lost."); // NOTE: it also can happen that if one of the command are "exit" the channel will be closed!
                            }
                            synchronized(lock){
                                long elapsedTimeWithoutData = (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimeConsumedData);
                                if (elapsedTimeWithoutData > maxTimeWithoutAnyData) {
                                    log(elapsedTimeWithoutData / 1000 + " secs elapsed without any data reception. Notifying command producer.", Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
                                    lock.notify(); // command producer is waiting for this
                                    try {
                                        lock.wait(500); // wait til we have new commands.
                                        Thread.yield();
                                        log("Continuing consumer loop. commandProducerThread.isAlive()?" + commandProducerThread.isAlive(), Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
                                        if(!commandProducerThread.isAlive()){
                                            log("No more commands to be issued and it's been too long without data reception. Exiting consumer.", Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        log(e, Project.MSG_VERBOSE);                                                
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    lastTimeConsumedData = System.currentTimeMillis(); // resets watch
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new BuildException(e);
                    }
                }
            };

            thread.start();
            commandProducerThread.start();
            thread.join(maxwait);

            if (thread.isAlive()) {
                // ran out of time
                thread = null;
                if (getFailonerror()) {
                    throw new BuildException(TIMEOUT_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    log(TIMEOUT_MESSAGE, Project.MSG_ERR);
                }
            } else {
                //success
                if (outputFile != null) {
                    writeToFile(out.toString(), append, outputFile);
                }

                // this is the wrong test if the remote OS is OpenVMS,
                // but there doesn't seem to be a way to detect it.
                log("Exit status (not reliable): " + channel.getExitStatus(), Project.MSG_INFO);
//                int ec = channel.getExitStatus(); FIXME
//                if (ec != 0) {
//                    String msg = "Remote command failed with exit status " + ec;
//                    if (getFailonerror()) {
//                        throw new BuildException(msg);
//                    } else {
//                        log(msg, Project.MSG_ERR);
//                    }
//                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new BuildException(e);
        } finally {
            if (session != null && session.isConnected()) {
                session.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    private void commandMode() {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = openSession();
            /* called once */
            if (command != null) {
                log("cmd : " + command, Project.MSG_INFO);
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = executeCommand(session, command);
                if (outputProperty != null) {
                    //#bugzilla 43437
                    getProject().setNewProperty(outputProperty, command + " : " + out);
                }
            } else { // read command resource and execute for each command
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(commandResource.getInputStream()));
                    String cmd;
                    String output = "";
                    while ((cmd = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        log("cmd : " + cmd, Project.MSG_INFO);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = executeCommand(session, cmd);
                        output += cmd + " : " + out + "\n";
                    }
                    if (outputProperty != null) {
                        //#bugzilla 43437
                        getProject().setNewProperty(outputProperty, output);
                    }
                    FileUtils.close(br);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new BuildException(e);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            throw new BuildException(e);
        } finally {
            if (session != null && session.isConnected()) {
                session.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    private ByteArrayOutputStream executeCommand(Session session, String cmd)
        throws BuildException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        TeeOutputStream tee = new TeeOutputStream(out, new KeepAliveOutputStream(System.out));

        try {
            final ChannelExec channel;
            session.setTimeout((int) maxwait);
            /* execute the command */
            channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
            channel.setCommand(cmd);
            channel.setOutputStream(tee);
            channel.setExtOutputStream(tee);
            channel.connect();
            // wait for it to finish
            thread =
                new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (!channel.isClosed()) {
                            if (thread == null) {
                                return;
                            }
                            try {
                                sleep(RETRY_INTERVAL);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // ignored
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

            thread.start();
            thread.join(maxwait);

            if (thread.isAlive()) {
                // ran out of time
                thread = null;
                if (getFailonerror()) {
                    throw new BuildException(TIMEOUT_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    log(TIMEOUT_MESSAGE, Project.MSG_ERR);
                }
            } else {
                //success
                if (outputFile != null) {
                    writeToFile(out.toString(), append, outputFile);
                }

                // this is the wrong test if the remote OS is OpenVMS,
                // but there doesn't seem to be a way to detect it.
                int ec = channel.getExitStatus();
                if (ec != 0) {
                    String msg = "Remote command failed with exit status " + ec;
                    if (getFailonerror()) {
                        throw new BuildException(msg);
                    } else {
                        log(msg, Project.MSG_ERR);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (BuildException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            if (e.getMessage().indexOf("session is down") >= 0) {
                if (getFailonerror()) {
                    throw new BuildException(TIMEOUT_MESSAGE, e);
                } else {
                    log(TIMEOUT_MESSAGE, Project.MSG_ERR);
                }
            } else {
                if (getFailonerror()) {
                    throw new BuildException(e);
                } else {
                    log("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Project.MSG_ERR);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (getFailonerror()) {
                throw new BuildException(e);
            } else {
                log("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage(), Project.MSG_ERR);
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    /**
     * Writes a string to a file. If destination file exists, it may be
     * overwritten depending on the "append" value.
     *
     * @param from           string to write
     * @param to             file to write to
     * @param append         if true, append to existing file, else overwrite
     * @exception Exception  most likely an IOException
     */
    private void writeToFile(String from, boolean append, File to)
        throws IOException {
        FileWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileWriter(to.getAbsolutePath(), append);
            StringReader in = new StringReader(from);
            char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead;
            while (true) {
                bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            out.flush();
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple workaround is to source the user's `.bash_profile` before running your commands:

```
<sshexec host="somehost"
    username="${username}"
    password="${password}"
    command="source ~/.bash_profile &amp;&amp; set"/>
```

Comment: when I use command="source ~/.bash_profile &amp;&amp; set"/>  , I got the error like
  [sshexec] Connecting to somehost:22
  [sshexec] sh: source
[sshexec] : not found
And when I run a shell script like command="/home/aykut/myscript", ant is freezing. What can cause that?

Answer (score 0):

Great post chubbsondubs. I needed to set the ORACLE SID then execute a PLSQL script that does not have the proper exit. Hence the echo exit piped.

```
        <sshexec host="${db.ipaddr}"

            verbose="true"
            trust="true"
            username="${scp.oracle.userid}"
            password="${scp.oracle.password}"
            command="echo exit | /bin/bash -l -c 'export ORACLE_SID=${db.name} ; sqlplus ${db.dbo.userid}/${db.dbo.password} @./INSTALL_REVPORT/CreateDatabase/gengrant.sql'"

        />
```